# Print array element syntax

Tags: theming

I am using devel and `<?php dpm($items); ?>` in my field template file so the node looks like the following.

[image: screenshot]

I can print the #theme element (which is a string) with the following code.

```
<?php print $items[0]['#theme']; ?>
```

What is the syntax to print elements in an array such as URLs, labels, titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to follow the trail in the DPM structure. The **url** field is under the **#element** element. The **#element** element is under the **0** element. This means you can access the value of **url** with:

```
$items[0]['#element']['url'];
```

You can reach the **title** element in a similar way.

The value of **#theme** is directly under the **0** element, that is why you could access it with:

```
$items[0]['#theme']
```

Comment: @ Jesse thanks but I don't want to use dpm I want to use print ie corresponding to my #theme example. By url I meant the url element of the #element array ie the one highlighted in red in the screenshot ie what is the syntax to print this string?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The elements URL and label are in your $items array, what do you mean with printing them in an array?

Comment: Ok let me try again - I can print the #theme string with  '<?php print $items[0]['#theme']; ?>' Now I want to do the same thing for the url string (the one highlighted in red) ie to print just the url string on its own. I think the answer I am looking for will be something like '<?php print $items[0]['#url']; ?>'

Comment: Ah, it should be `<?php print $items[0]['#element']['url']; ?>` I'll update my answer to explain

Answer (score 1):

where did you output the `dpm`? double click on any of the attributes then it shows you the trail array which displays that content. like this

[image]

then use this array key at the beginning of the variable passed in your hook preprocess function. for example:

```
function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables){
    $variables['value'] = $variables['revision_timestamp']
}
```